# How to pass a jQuery or Javascript object/collection to Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

Is there a way I can pass Snap.svg a jQuery object (say, a collection of all `<line>` elements) and "convert" it so that Snap.svg can use it (eg. animate it)?

Example:

```
//this is jQuery code (or Javascript querySelectorAll if you like)
var lines = $('line');

/* there is some step missing here that converts 
the lines variable to a usable Snap object */

//this is Snap.svg code
lines.forEach(function(e) {
    e.animate({ 'x1': 80, 'y1': 120 }, 3000);
});
```

The reason I can't use the Snap.svg native `selectAll()` function is that I'm using a custom SVG namespace to save additional attribute data to the `<line>` elements. I'd rather use some Snap.svg code akin to `svg.selectAll('customns:var1="3"')` but that doesn't work because querySelectorAll does not support custom namespaces and with jQuery or plain Javascript I could work around that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could probably use jquery to do the loop, and then Snapify each DOM element, like Snap(someDOMelement).animate(...);

Comment: Have you tried filtering `.selectAll()` array? The `var1="3"` is found inside the `attributes` sub-array.

Comment: @Ian @AlvinK. Thanks for your help, guys! By now I had a solution figured out, but it was really unelegant, so I tried both your suggestions. In the end, I got Ian's to work very well. Alvin's solution I had trouble with, as Snap.svg seems to lack a native filter function for its `set`s, so I used `jQuery.grep()` but that discarded other vital parts of the Snap array. Would one of you like to write up an answer so I can accept it? Otherwise I'll post my own findings. Thanks again.

Comment: I think post your own findings and answer!